# Doctrine/ORM - invalid Relation mapping while creating entity

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine, relation

I encountered invalid parameters binding while persisting new entity with OneToOneRelation
Current behavior

I have two entities: Invoice and InvoiceNumeration

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Payments\Invoicing\Domain;

use Core\Database\DateTimeTrait;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\HasLifecycleCallbacks;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;
use OpenApi\Attributes as OA;
use Payments\Domain\PaymentId;

#[OA\Schema]
#[Entity]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'invoices')]
#[HasLifecycleCallbacks]
class Invoice
{
    use DateTimeTrait;

    #[Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'InvoiceIdType')]
    #[Serializer\Exclude]
    private InvoiceId $id;

    #[ORM\Column(name: 'payment_id', type: 'PaymentIdDoctrineType')]
    #[Serializer\Exclude]
    private PaymentId $paymentId;

    #[OA\Property]
    #[ORM\Column(name: 'type')]
    private string $invoiceType;

    #[OA\Property]
    #[ORM\Embedded]
    #[Serializer\Exclude]
    private InvoiceDetails $invoiceDetails;

    #[OA\Property]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?string $file = null;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity: InvoiceNumeration::class, cascade: ['DETACH'], fetch: 'EAGER')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'id', referencedColumnName: 'invoice_id', nullable: true)]
    private InvoiceNumeration $numeration;

    public function __construct(PaymentId $paymentId, InvoiceDetails $invoiceDetails, InvoiceType $invoiceType)
    {
        $this->id = InvoiceId::generate();
        $this->paymentId = $paymentId;
        $this->invoiceDetails = $invoiceDetails;
        $this->invoiceType = $invoiceType->getName();
    }

    public function getId(): InvoiceId
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setFile(string $file): void
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    public function getDetails(): InvoiceDetails
    {
        return $this->invoiceDetails;
    }

    public function getType(): InvoiceType
    {
        return InvoiceTypeFactory::fromName($this->invoiceType);
    }
}
```

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Payments\Invoicing\Domain;

use Core\Database\DateTimeTrait;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

#[Entity]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'invoice_numeration')]
#[ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks]
class InvoiceNumeration
{
    use DateTimeTrait;

    #[Id]
    #[ORM\Column(name: 'invoice_id', type: 'InvoiceIdType')]
    #[Serializer\Exclude]
    private InvoiceId $invoiceId;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 4)]
    private int $year;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 2)]
    private string $month;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private string $type;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 6)]
    private string $number;

    #[Serializer\Accessor(getter: 'getNumber')]
    private string $fullNumber;

    public function __construct(InvoiceId $invoiceId, InvoiceNumber $invoiceNumber, InvoiceType $invoiceType)
    {
        $this->invoiceId = $invoiceId;
        $this->type = $invoiceType->shortName();
        $this->year = $invoiceNumber->getYear();
        $this->month = $invoiceNumber->getMonth();
        $this->number = $invoiceNumber->getOrdinalNumber();
    }

    public function getNumber(): InvoiceNumber
    {
        return new InvoiceNumber("$this->type/$this->year/$this->month/$this->number");
    }
}
```

While I'm creating Invoice entity, doctrine throws a pdo exception

```
START TRANSACTION
```

```
INSERT INTO invoices (id, payment_id, type, file, date_created, date_updated, invoiceDetails_seller_name, invoiceDetails_seller_country, invoiceDetails_seller_city, invoiceDetails_seller_zipcode, invoiceDetails_description) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

```
ROLLBACK
```

```
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id' cannot be null: #0 /app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Connection.php(1907): Doctrine\\DBAL…
```

When checking deeper, it seems id is not being passed to PDO, I see null there.

[image]

DDL:

```
`create table invoices(id                            binary(16)               not nullprimary key,payment_id                    binary(16)               not null,file                          varchar(255)             null,date_created                  datetime                 not null,date_updated                  datetime                 null,invoiceDetails_seller_name    varchar(255)             not null,invoiceDetails_seller_country varchar(255)             not null,invoiceDetails_seller_city    varchar(255)             not null,invoiceDetails_seller_zipcode varchar(255)             not null,invoiceDetails_description    varchar(255)             not null,type                          enum ('proforma', 'vat') not null);
```

```
create table invoice_numeration(invoice_id   binary(16)              not nullprimary key,year         int                     not null,month        varchar(2)              not null,type         enum ('FV', 'PROFORMA') not null,number       int                     not null,date_created datetime                not null,date_updated datetime                null,constraint invoice_numeration_pkunique (year, number, month, type));
```

Of course, everything worked before adding OneToOne and JoinColumn definition.
Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

I would not use JoinColumn, because it seems not be necessary, but when I don't it throws another exception

Could not resolve type of column "id" of class "Payments\Invoicing\Domain\InvoiceNumeration"

However, it's the same type as in Invoice Entity Id

I've tried also OneToMany/ManyToOne relation, but the effect is the same, but on the other entity.